# jquery pre select select option dropdown in wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have tried these options:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#adv_actions_shortcode").val("verhuur");     
});
```

and

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#adv_actions_shortcode option[value=verhuur]").prop("selected", true);    
});
```

The url is http://makelaarcorrect.test.hetkanbeteronline.nl/woningaanbod-verhuur/

I must be forgetting something, anyone can help me out?

Comment: jQuery("#adv_actions_shortcode") is returning a div.  divs don't have a value attribute

Comment: You appear to be using some plugin to create your non standard dropdowns.  they are not <select> elements with nested <option> s.  You'll need to figure out what plugin you are using and find the api for it to find out how to dynamically change the values.  You can see this by right clicking on one of the elements and choosing to inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a non-standard dropdown menu. This could be a plugin or something else. You could trigger a click on the correct element by using jQuery instead by using the following code.

```
jQuery("#adv_actions_shortcode").parent().find('[data-value="verkoop"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You're so quick. I also think like you. Btw, they are the bootstrap dropdown-menu.

Comment: Thnx did did not worked out for me... need to figure out how to trigger the click.